# How to Sync Gmail's "Other" Contacts with OS X Yosemite (Mail.app and Contacts) and iOS Mail

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, contacts, gmail

I'm trying to get Mail.app on OS X Yosemite to autocomplete contacts on my Gmail "Other" group - i.e. the contacts google creates for you once you've sent them an email.

I have a Google "Internet Account" setup in OS X, which syncs Google's contacts, but only the ones in my Gmail "Address Book", which does not include the earlier "Other".

If I try to set up a CarDav account in Contacts with my gmail credentials it tells me it's a duplicate, and if I try to add some extra dots to my email, it will create my account, but immediately turn it into a Google account as opposed to a CarDav.

I would ideally like to achieve a similar setup on iOS, having the Gmail "Other" available for autocomplete on iOS Mail

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Mail.app and Contacts.app have no access to the "Others" group from gmail...

however, if you compose all your gmail account messages in Mail.app on iOS or OS X instead of the gmail web client, they will autofill any addresses you have previously sent to.

Comment: I remember at some point (in an older version of OS X) it had synced all my contacts, including Other. I don't remember if this had been done through CarDav or another system. Has this capability been removed?

Comment: you used to be able to add recently contacted to specific contact groups in gmail, but it seems that's no longer the case.